# CPU/Memory Monitoring in Heroku (for Java)

Tags: java, memory, heroku, monitoring, cpu

Is there a way to have a ganglia / munin type setup that monitors simple CPU and Memory use on the Heroku Platform?.
Specifically I'm using Java, not Ruby. (in case that matters).

I see the New Relic add on, but It's not exactly clear to me that it will do what I want, or how to configure it for Java.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you need this figures for?  Neither of them are limits on Heroku and not something that you can control.

Comment: Just want to see trending, to determine if changes in my app take more/less memory. See what kind of load I'm under, Should I add more dynos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[New Relic is available for Java on Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#java). It will show you memory usage for your app in the Dynos tab of the New Relic web UI, along with how busy your dynos are and what the request queue depth is. There is a [memory limit per dyno on Heroku](http://policy.heroku.com/aup), so it's not a bad idea to track memory usage.

There's a [Ruby gem](https://github.com/newrelic/heroku-newrelic-java-install) you can use to more easily install the New Relic Java agent on Heroku.